# What is causing my memory issues in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to PySpark, and I am trying to code a Random Forest Regression model to predict the amount of buffering that occurs during a streaming session according to various network metrics. The model will run on a dataset file stored in the Hadoop Distributed File System. The file is 9MB in size, for context.

I've been using two Ubuntu virtual machines on Oracle VirtualBox, a master and a slave. I've been encountering issues with memory, and am a little bit confused as to why these are occurring.

My code is as follows:

```
#Importing libraries
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, FloatType
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean, col
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.regression import RandomForestRegressor
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.tuning import ParamGridBuilder
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Defining fields
Fields = [StructField("NbClients", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("BottleneckBW", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("BottleneckDelay", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("ClientResolution", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("RequestDuration", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("TCPOutputPacket", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("TCPOutputDelay", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("TCPOutputJitter", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("TCPOutputPloss", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("TCPInputPacket", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("TCPInputDelay", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("TCPInputJitter", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("TCPInputPloss", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("TCPInputRetrans", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("50_InputRateVariation", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("StdInterATimesReq", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("50_InterATimesReq", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("AvgBufferLevel", FloatType(), True)
]

#Defining schema
Schema = StructType(fields=Fields)

#Starting Spark session
Spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://IPADDRESS:7077").getOrCreate()

#Reading CSV from file system
SparkDataFrame = Spark.read.csv("hdfs://IPADDRESS:9000/Dataset.csv", 
sep=",", header=True, schema=Schema)

#Assembling all the predictive features into one features column that is used by the random forest regressor
Assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=[
"NbClients",
"BottleneckBW",
"BottleneckDelay",
"ClientResolution",
"RequestDuration",
"TCPOutputPacket",
"TCPOutputDelay",
"TCPOutputJitter",
"TCPOutputPloss",
"TCPInputPacket",
"TCPInputDelay",
"TCPInputJitter",
"TCPInputPloss",
"TCPInputRetrans",
"50_InputRateVariation",
"StdInterATimesReq",
"50_InterATimesReq"], outputCol="QoSAndContextFeatures",
handleInvalid="keep")

#Creating random forest regressor, with AvgBufferLevel as the label column and the newly created vector QoSAndContextFeatures as the predictive column
RandomForestRegressionModel = RandomForestRegressor(labelCol="AvgBufferLevel", featuresCol="QoSAndContextFeatures")

#Creating a two-stage prediction pipeline that ensures that the data is always passed through the vector assembler prior to the random forest model being created
PredictionPipeline = Pipeline(stages=[Assembler, RandomForestRegressionModel])

#Creating a paramater grid to test for the most optimal hyperparameters of the random forest model
ParameterGrid = ParamGridBuilder() \
            .addGrid(RandomForestRegressionModel.numTrees, [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start=10, stop=100, num=5)]) \
            .addGrid(RandomForestRegressionModel.maxDepth, [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start=5, stop=50, num=5)]) \
            .build()

#Building a cross validator of the random forest model that encapsulates the prediction pipeline and the parameter grid alongside an evaluator
CrossValidation = CrossValidator(estimator=PredictionPipeline,
                             estimatorParamMaps=ParameterGrid,
                             evaluator=RegressionEvaluator(labelCol="AvgBufferLevel"),
                             numFolds=3)

#Splitting the data into training and testing data
(TrainingData, TestingData) = SparkDataFrame.randomSplit([0.8,0.2])

#Fitting the cross validated model to the training data
CrossValidatedModel = CrossValidation.fit(TrainingData)

#Making predictions on the testing data
Predictions = CrossValidatedModel.transform(TestingData)

#Declaring evaluator of RSquared to evaluate the RSquared of the model
RSquaredEvaluator = RegressionEvaluator(labelCol="AvgBufferLevel", predictionCol="Prediction", metric="r2")

#Declaring evaluator of RMSE to evaluate the RMSE of the model
RMSEEvaluator = RegressionEvaluator(labelCol="AvgBufferLevel", predictionCol="Prediction", metric="rmse")

#Calculating the RSquared of the model
RSquared = RSquaredEvaluator.evaluate(Predictions)

#Calculating the RMSE of the model
RMSE = RMSEEvaluator.evaluate(Predictions)

#Putting the mean observation of AvgBufferLevel from the test dataset into an array
MeanObservationArray = TestingData.select(mean(col("AvgBufferLevel"))).collect()

#Collecting the mean observation
MeanObservation = MeanObservationArray[0]

#Calculating the scatter index, which represents RMSE as a proportion of the mean observation
ScatterIndex = RMSE/MeanObservation

#Printing RSquared
print("R Squared:",RSquared)

#Printing RMSE
print("RMSE:",RMSE)

#Printing scatter index
print("Scatter Index:",ScatterIndex)
```

I firstly tried to run the model with each VM allocated 2GB of RAM, on a system with 8GB of RAM overall. However, when I tried to run the code in Spark on the master VM, I was getting this message from Linux occurring halfway through the execution:

```
Killed
```

I looked at the Spark master website to see what error was being outputted, and the error was something along the lines of:

```
ERROR CoarseGrainedBackEndExecutor: Driver disassociated.
```

When I searched up this error, I ascertained that it had something to do with there not being enough RAM, so I increased the RAM of each VM to 3GB and tried the code again. However, when I tried this, the slave VM was aborted by VirtualBox midway through execution due to my system not having enough RAM to facilitate the running of two Ubuntu VMs with 3GB of RAM.

As such, I had a go at simplifying my random forest code by removing the two-stage pipeline and setting hyperparameters prior to execution as opposed to searching for them. I wondered if these might be adding to the RAM intensity of my code, so I hoped that this might solve the issue. The simplified code was as follows:

```
#Importing libraries
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, FloatType
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean, col
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.regression import RandomForestRegressor
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.tuning import ParamGridBuilder
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Defining fields
Fields = [StructField("NbClients", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("BottleneckBW", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("BottleneckDelay", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("ClientResolution", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("RequestDuration", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("TCPOutputPacket", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("TCPOutputDelay", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("TCPOutputJitter", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("TCPOutputPloss", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("TCPInputPacket", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("TCPInputDelay", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("TCPInputJitter", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("TCPInputPloss", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("TCPInputRetrans", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("50_InputRateVariation", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("StdInterATimesReq", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("50_InterATimesReq", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("AvgBufferLevel", FloatType(), True)
]

#Defining schema
Schema = StructType(fields=Fields)

#Starting Spark session
Spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://192.168.56.112:7077").getOrCreate()

#Reading CSV from file system
SparkDataFrame = Spark.read.csv("hdfs://192.168.56.112:9000/CleanedAssignmentDataset.csv", 
sep=",", header=True, schema=Schema)

#Assembling all the predictive features into one features column that is used by the random forest regressor
Assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=[
"NbClients",
"BottleneckBW",
"BottleneckDelay",
"ClientResolution",
"RequestDuration",
"TCPOutputPacket",
"TCPOutputDelay",
"TCPOutputJitter",
"TCPOutputPloss",
"TCPInputPacket",
"TCPInputDelay",
"TCPInputJitter",
"TCPInputPloss",
"TCPInputRetrans",
"50_InputRateVariation",
"StdInterATimesReq",
"50_InterATimesReq"], outputCol="QoSAndContextFeatures",
handleInvalid="keep")

#Transforming DataFrame into vector with combined features column
AssembledData = Assembler.transform(SparkDataFrame)

#Creating random forest regressor, with AvgBufferLevel as the label column and the newly created vector QoSAndContextFeatures as the predictive column
RandomForestRegressionModel = RandomForestRegressor(labelCol="AvgBufferLevel", featuresCol="QoSAndContextFeatures", numTrees=100, maxDepth=30)

#Splitting the data into training and testing data
(TrainingData, TestingData) = AssembledData.randomSplit([0.8,0.2])

#Fitting the random forest to the training data
RandomForestFitted = RandomForestRegressionModel.fit(TrainingData)

#Making predictions on the testing data
Predictions = RandomForestFitted.transform(TestingData)

#Declaring evaluator of RSquared to evaluate the RSquared of the model
RSquaredEvaluator = RegressionEvaluator(labelCol="AvgBufferLevel", predictionCol="Prediction", metric="r2")

#Declaring evaluator of RMSE to evaluate the RMSE of the model
RMSEEvaluator = RegressionEvaluator(labelCol="AvgBufferLevel", predictionCol="Prediction", metric="rmse")

#Calculating the RSquared of the model
RSquared = RSquaredEvaluator.evaluate(Predictions)

#Calculating the RMSE of the model
RMSE = RMSEEvaluator.evaluate(Predictions)

#Putting the mean observation of AvgBufferLevel from the test dataset into an array
MeanObservationArray = TestingData.select(mean(col("AvgBufferLevel"))).collect()

#Collecting the mean observation
MeanObservation = MeanObservationArray[0]

#Calculating the scatter index, which represents RMSE as a proportion of the mean observation
ScatterIndex = RMSE/MeanObservation

#Printing RSquared
print("R Squared:",RSquared)

#Printing RMSE
print("RMSE:",RMSE)

#Printing scatter index
print("Scatter Index:",ScatterIndex)
```

However, this code still returned the same problems; it was still killed by Linux when I allocated 2GB, and the slave VM still died midway through execution when I allocated 3GB.

As such, I decided to try the code out on a system with 16GB of RAM. I reconfigured the VMs to have 4GB of RAM each on this system, but when I tried to run even the simplified code, Linux returned "Killed" midway through execution.

As such, I decided to try increasing the RAM on each VM to 5GB and running the simplified code. However, I received the following error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I did some research, and I checked the spark-default.conf file. My Spark memory default is set to 5GB in that file.

I must admit that I'm absolutely stumped by what could be causing this error. For some context, I'm not exactly trying to churn a massive dataset here; my dataset CSV file is only 9MB in size. Also, I've managed to code a Random Forest Regressor in regular Python, using the SciKit Learn library, and that managed to run fine even on the lower-powered 8GB system, even with a parameter grid search and all. It took a minute or two to run, but it ran fine.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing my memory issues, as I'll admit that I'm very stuck?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: File sizes and code simplification doesn't affect the size of the JVM heap given to the spark-submit command. Spark doesn't know it's running in a VM or other hardware either. If spark-default.conf says 5G is given to every executor, then your system can barely run only one executor

Comment: Thank you for the response. Does that mean that my code might work if I decrease the amount of RAM given to every executor to, say, 2GB or a similar lower value within the spark-default.conf file?

Comment: The OS itself also needs memory, so yes. There will be one driver and one to many executors for any Spark job. You can run many Spark workers on separate VMs to distribute the work, but they all need to have enough memory to run all started jobs. The Spark UI can show resource utilization

Comment: I tried decreasing spark.driver.memory (the setting set to 5g in the config file) to 2g, and the OutOfMemoryError still persisted.

Comment: But how many executors are running? Do you really need VMs to run Spark? Why not let it run completely within your host? Spark automatically can distribute itself on a single server, and doesn't need an external master server. Also, HDFS is not needed for any files less than 128MB in size

Comment: From having looked at the Spark UI, I have 2 executors running, with each being allocated 1024MB of RAM. This doesn’t seem to change regardless of what my VM RAMs are set to.

Comment: I’ve now tried altering the RAM of each executor to 2GB, and that does clear my initial error, but it now seems to be the case that Spark times out and just randomly kills off executors halfway through execution… I’m honestly wondering whether it might be easier to train my model using SciKit Learn and then just test it using HDFS/Spark.

Comment: _doesn’t seem to change regardless of what my VM RAMs are set to_ - Correct, as mentioned, Spark does not know it is running in a VM, and there is no way to tell it. You would modify only `spark-defaults.conf`, or `spark-env.sh` files, or otherwise override values on the `spark-submit` command. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: One thing that could help but I don't guarantee is , don't run long pipelines at one go. Materialize your dataframe using `df.cache().count()` and uncache previous ones. This won't be your issue since your file size is only 9mb.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have now managed to get to the bottom of this problem and get my code to work.

Following further investigation, I think the problem was caused by the fact that I was being a tad too ambitious with the hyperparameters of the Random Forest Regressor. When I played about with lower hyperparameters, the code worked perfectly, and the “killing” stopped.

Thank you all very much for your help!